# IHttpClientFactory with autofac Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I m trying to use httpclient and sometimes I get an error when I call a 3rd party Rest api using IHttpClient. Here is my code:

```
public class MyHttpService : IMyHttpService, ILifetimeScopeDependency
{
    private readonly AppSettings appSettings;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;
    
    public MyHttpService(AppSettings settings,
                                IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        appSettings = settings;
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<List<ResultDto>> GetData(DateTime from, DateTime to, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string url = $"https://www.myurl.com/api/v3/data/?api_key={appSettings.key}" +
                     $"&start_date={GetDate(from)}&end_date={GetDate(to)}";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultDto>>(responseStream);
    }
}
```

and the exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it (or one of its parent scopes) has already been disposed.
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(Object tag)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope()
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandlerEntry(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String name)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactoryExtensions.CreateClient(IHttpClientFactory factory)
   at My.MicroServices.Data.Infrastructure.MyHttpService.GetData(DateTime from, DateTime to, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\MyPc\My.MicroServices.Data\src\My.MicroServices.Data\Infrastructure\MyHttpService.cs:line 43
```

I have added `services.AddHttpClient();` in `Startup.cs/ConfiguresServices`

Anyone knows why am I getting this error?

Comment: Is it intermittent with same query, or only fails every time with same query?  Do you know the HTTP status  that gets returned?

Comment: It does not fail always. Problem is when ```httpClientFactory.CreateClient();``` gets called

Comment: That is strange since I would expect it would fail on the send.  Maybe there is already a process running for api.  Maybe the API need a resource that isn't available.  You need to talk to the API people.

Comment: HttpClientFactory will re-use its HttpMessageHandler. It sounds like one request creates an HttpMessageHandler (on-demand) and then the next request tries to reuse it. What I find odd is that `DefaultHttpClientFactory` is calling `CreateScope`, so this is creating an inner DI scope just for the request handler stack... And the exception seems to be complaining that the *original* parent scope (for the first request) has been disposed. A minimal repro (including DI config) would be useful.